# Wrap A Callable and Runnable with Spring Transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have custom Anonymous classes Callable and Runnable and I need to enforce transactions around the ENTIRE call of Callable and Runnable.

I am using Spring JPA 2.0 and Spring framework 5.   Is there a Programmatic way to surround @Transaction behavior for Anonymous classes Callable and Runnable?

```
@Transaction
public V call() throw Exception{
    this.mymethod();// NOTE THIS IS NOT SURROUNDDED BY TXN
    dao.method()

}

@Transaction
public void run(){
   this.mymethod()// NOTE THIS IS NOT SURROUNDDED BY TXN
   dao.method()

} 
@Transaction
public void run(){
   this.mymethod1()// NOTE THIS IS NOT SURROUNDED BY TXN because of this
   this.mymethod2() // NOTE THIS IS NOT SURROUNDED BY TXN  because of this

}
```

Putting @Transaction does not work.  Can you please help how to wrap Programmatically Callable and Runnable?

Spring JPA: 2.2.3.RELEASE
Spring  5.2.2.RELEASE 
Spring Boot: 2.2.2.RELEASE

Any pointer will greatly be appreciated.

Let me clarify some points:

I wanted to

```
CallableTXNDecorator<V> 
public V call() throw Exception{
{
   start TXN
    try{
    targetcallable.call();
     commmit()
    }catch(Exception e){
      rollback()
    }
}
```

So I wanted to write Wrapper that does that.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but the Spring `TransactionTemplate` might help https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html

Comment: simply call another bean's transactional method from the callable: `() -> someBean.someTransactionalMethod()`

Comment: @JBNizet,  Does my above example work for this.method()? Since it is proxied it will not therefor I wanted to create TXNWrapper runnable or callable which I can wrap in Thread Pool execute or submit methods.

Comment: @JensSchauder,  Spring Does not have any utility to wrap Callable and Runnable?  Do we have to manually do this? This is a common use case where we have a mix of 'this' and bean class used in callable or runnable anonymous class.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Simply call **another** bean's transactional method from the callable: `() -> someBean.someTransactionalMethod()`

Comment: @JBNizet, Anonymous class may only have access to **this** only in that case I need it to wrap it programmatically.  Do you think  `TransactionTemplate` would work where we have mix **someProxyBean** and **this** ?

Comment: Sure, you can use TransactionTemplate. But I find it simpler and cleaner to have callables simply delegate to a bean.